# ошибка при запуске скрипта python в командной строке

Tags: python

написал программу, она читает файл, анализирует и выдает данные. Запускаю через командную строку и идет обращение к библиотеке[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и не работает

```
spis=[]
with open("D:\\программы\\file.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line=line.strip()
        spis+=(line)
spis=spis.split(' ')


dl=len(spis)
a=0
b=0
c=0
for i in range(dl):
    spis[i]=spis[i].split(';')
for i in range(dl):
  sred=(int(spis[i][1])+int(spis[i][2])+int(spis[i][3]))/3
  print(sred)
  a+=int(spis[i][1])
  b+=int(spis[i][2])
  c+=int(spis[i][3])
a/=dl
b/=dl
c/=dl
print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: А вы кодировочки для кириллицы указали?

Comment: не совсем понял вопроса). путь к программе и программа да на кириллице

Comment: Попробуйте добавить параметр encoding='utf-8' или 'cp1251', насчет второго не знаю, но первое помогло мне когда у меня неправильно отображался русский текст.

Comment: а это куда вставлять подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @НикитаЗинин в open параметром после имени файла через запятую

Comment: что-то вроде open('path to file', 'параметр если хотите (r или w)', encoding = 'utf-8')

Comment: благодарю за совет

Comment: не параметры utf-8 b cp1251 не работают*

Comment: Попробуйте указать путь к файлу на латинице и сам файл назовите на латинице, возможно проблема именно в кодировке

Comment: вариант все на латинице тоже не работает